# Android app to create nested folders on home screen

Tags: android

I'm looking for an app that can create nested folders on Home screen.

For example, Home Screen → some XYZ icons scattered on it → those icons are moved into a folder F1 → this folder is moved into a new folder F2 which already has some ABC icons.

Now, it would  be F2 which has ABC icons and F1 folder (as an icon just like any ABC icon) inside it. Tapping F1 folder icon  would now show its own XYZ icons.

It seems that [Folder Organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abcOrganizer.lite) can easily do the job but it doesn't blend with Lollipop UI (the white background, smooth font and all cheesy stuff), so you ultimately end up with a *weird* nested folder. I believe it is because  the app's UI hasn't been redeveloped for Lollipop's Material design.

**Whatever the case may be, is there any app that suits my need?**

---

**OS Support:** Android Lollipop

**Pricing:** Freeware or paid (up to $10)

**Device Status**: Rooted and Xposed Framework installed.

Comment: Users: Please add a relevant tag here.

Comment: Meanwhile, I asked a similar question on [Android.se] and answered it [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/120958/96277).